# Is locking required when reading and writing tuple headers in MVCC?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Several locks are introduced in MySQL, among which `SELECT ... FROM` is a consistent read, a snapshot of the read data and no lock is set (unless the transaction level is `SERIALIZABLE`)  (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html)

The snapshot (MVCC) is implemented in MySQL by adding a header (including transaction version and pointer) and logical visibility rules to the tuple

But we always emphasize the design principle of the visibility rule, but ignore the fact that reading and writing to the tuple Header are two mutually exclusive actions, which can only be avoided by locking.

So how does the sentence of consistent read without lock understand? Is it just that there is no lock in a broad sense? How is the atomic reading and writing of the tuple Header designed? Is there any performance overhead? Is there any information available in this regard?

----- supplementary instruction -----

When a row(tuple) is updated, the new version of the row is kept, along with the old copy/copies. Each copy has a sequence number (transaction id) with it.

The transaction ID and the pointer to the copies are stored in the row header, that is, when creating a copies, you need to modify the row header (update the transaction ID and the pointer to the copies). When accessing the row, you need to access the row header first to judge the version (location) we want to access.

Modifying the row header and visiting row header should be two mutually exclusive actions (otherwise dirty data will be read in the case of concurrent reading and writing), and what I want to know is that MySQL performs this part (row header) How is the logic of reading and writing designed? Is it a read-write lock / spin lock or is there any other clever method？

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer goes something like this.

When a row is updated, the new version of the row is kept, along with the old copy/copies.  Each copy has a sequence number (transaction id) with it.  After both transactions `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`, the set of rows is cleaned up -- the surviving one is kept; the other(s) are tossed.

That sequence number has the effect of labeling rows as being part of the snapshot that of the dataset that was taken at `BEGIN` time.

Rows with sequence numbers that are equal to or older than the transaction in question are considered as fair game for *reading* by the transaction.  Note that no lock is needed for such a "consistent read".

Each copy of the row has its own tuple header, with a different sequence number.  The copies are chained together in a "history list".  Updates/deletes to the row will add new items to the list, but leave the old copies unchanged.  (Again, this points out that no lock is needed for an old read.)

Transaction isolation "read dirty" allows the transaction to go through the history list to 'see' the latest copy.

Performance overhead?  Sure.  Everything has a performance overhead.  But...  The "performance" that matters is the grand total of all actions.  There is a lot of *complexity*, but the end result is 'better' performance.

The history list is a lot of overhead, but it helps by decreasing the locking, etc.

InnoDB uses "optimistic" locking -- That is it starts a transaction with the assumption (hope) that it will `COMMIT`.  The cost is that `ROLLBACK` is less efficient.  This seems like a reasonable tradeoff.

InnoDB has a lot of overhead, yet it can beat the much-simpler MyISAM Engine in many benchmarks.  Faster *and* ACID -- May as well get rid of MyISAM.  And that is the direction Oracle is taking MySQL.

Comment: You are right，When a row(tuple) is updated, the new version of the row is kept, along with the old copy/copies. Each copy has a sequence number (transaction id) with it.               The transaction ID and the pointer to the copies are stored in the row header, that is, when creating a copies, you need to modify the row header (update the transaction ID and the pointer to the copies). When accessing the row, you need to access the row header first to judge the version (location) we want to access

Comment: Modifying the row header and visiting row header should be two mutually exclusive actions (otherwise dirty data will be read in the case of concurrent reading and writing), and what I want to know is that MySQL performs this part (row header) How is the logic of reading and writing designed?Is it a read-write lock / spin lock or is there any other clever method?

Comment: @Zeng -  Search for Jeremy Cole -- he has some blogs with more details.

Comment: I searched for articles about him, but didn't find anything related to this topic. I also left a comment on his blog, but I haven't gotten a reply yet. You know a lot of experts in this area. Can you help some people in Aite? I am very grateful.

Comment: @Zeng - percona.com has lots of pages; some might get into the details you desire.

Comment: @Zeng if you want so much details about mysql inner workings, then 1) SO is not the right place for you as this is a programming QA site and your question is not about a programming problem. You need database professionals at the DBA site. 2) for such detailed question you may need to look at mysql's source code and see how they exactly implemented repeatable reads.